# Why is this question *unclear* instead of *too broad*?

Tags: discussion

I voted to close (yes, the first VtC I cast in my life) [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36063936/python-pseudo-code#36063936) as *too broad*. Most people, however, VtCed for being *unclear*.

Since VtC should have as goal help users to fix their question (and personally hate when people VtCs for dumb reasons), I'd like to actually do it in a helpful way.

Why would this question be considered *unclear* instead of *too broad*? In my case, I think I clearly understood his problem, but I don't think there's a finite set of available answers to the problem (additionally I think it is clearly OT).

Comment: I know I'd go with unclear.  There's just not clear what he's actually looking for; what qualities he's looking for in an answer.  I can certainly understand why you'd close it as Too Broad, and I think either could apply, but my instincts would indeed be that it's just not clear what he wants, given that pseudocode doesn't actually have a rigid definition (by design).

Comment: Mmmm yep, makes sense to me

Answer (score 5):

His requirements are unclear. We all know what pseudo code is, but his intentions are unknown. What was he trying to achieve with the pseudo code?

That all aside, the question is off-topic for SO also, since we're not a code translation service.

That's 3 closure reasons that applied, already:

- Unclear.
- Too broad.
- Off-topic.

The whole "point" of closing questions isn't necessarily to make users fix them.

It's primary purpose is more like a kind of quality control, while *allowing* users who had their questions closed a second chance to improve it.

Oh, and the question is deleted, now.